# Отправка данных из MS SQL в PHP методом POST

Tags: php, sql-server

нужна помощь или помогите статьей\советом.

У меня есть форма на php для отправки СМСок, этой форме нужны переменные:

```
$numberin1 = $_POST['number'];
$text = $_POST['text'];
```

я создал на HTML визуальную часть, куда я и вбиваю номер телефона и текст

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Событие onclick</title>

 </head> 
<body>
    <form action="http://10.200.5.10/sms/smsout.php" method="post">
    Номер:  <input type="text" name="number" /><br />
    Сообщение: <input type="text" name="text" /><br />
   <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Отправь меня!" />

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

в ручном режиме все работает хорошо. Но мне нужно что-бы переменные number и text отправлялись из MS-SQL.

в чем собственно и вопрос, что писать в процедуре что-бы она выполнялось джобом ?

как взять переменные из базы с этим вопросов нету, как их отправить на http://10.200.5.10/sms/smsout.php методом post. не могу найти в интернете, а то что нахожу не совсем то, что мне нужно.

Comment: curl вам поможет

Comment: curl -d  "http://10.200.5.10/sms/smsout.php?number=+711111111&text=Отправка смс из базы" "uri" правильно ли я понял должно выглядит вот так?

Comment: Ну если хотите тянуть данные из бд средствами php, то лучше через https://www.php.net/manual/ru/book.curl.php

Comment: нет! я может не правильно изъяснился, я не хочу тянуть данные, мне нужно просто их отправить. то есть, джоб смотрит есть ли активное задание у сотрудника и отправляет ему уведомление "Дорогой друг у тебя задание"

Comment: А как джоб узнает есть ли активные задания? Будет тянуть из БД ?

Comment: в джобе будет запрос который будет проверять есть ли задание,если есть, берет номер телефона из другой таблицы подставляет в переменную номера и отправляет сообщение, джоб будет запускаться раз в час(к примеру). мой план был такой

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/108029/discussion-between-ghostkhimki-and-archdemon).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение оказалось банальным, нужно взять powershell скрипт,`$postParams = @{number=@args[0];text=@args[1]}
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri http://10.200.5.10/sms/smsout.php -Method POST -Body $postParams`

и создать job который и запускает скрипт с нужными параметрами из базы